# Adding Headers to Exported CSV file from Excel Worksheet

Tags: vba, excel, csv, macros

I am working on finding a solution that will handle adding some pre-determined headers to a CSV file that gets exported from an Excel worksheet. I am applying a solution added by BruceWayne and when I apply the VBA code to my current Excel worksheet, it adds the headers to the Excel spreadsheet itself.

I am trying to find a way to have this VBA code be applied to the exported CSV file itself and not the Excel spreadsheet. My VBA code currently looks as such:

```
Sub WriteCSVFile()

Dim My_filenumber As Integer
Dim logSTR As String

My_filenumber = FreeFile

logSTR = logSTR & Cells(18, "C").Value & " , "
logSTR = logSTR & Cells(19, "C").Value & " , "
logSTR = logSTR & Cells(20, "C").Value & " , "
logSTR = logSTR & Cells(21, "C").Value & " , "
logSTR = logSTR & Cells(22, "C").Value & " , "
logSTR = logSTR & Cells(26, "C").Value & " , "
logSTR = logSTR & Cells(27, "C").Value & " , "
logSTR = logSTR & Cells(28, "C").Value & " , "
logSTR = logSTR & Cells(29, "C").Value & " , "
logSTR = logSTR & Cells(30, "C").Value & " , "
logSTR = logSTR & Cells(31, "C").Value & " , "
logSTR = logSTR & Cells(32, "C").Value & " , "
logSTR = logSTR & Cells(36, "C").Value & " , "
logSTR = logSTR & Cells(37, "C").Value & " , "
logSTR = logSTR & Cells(38, "C").Value & " , "
logSTR = logSTR & Cells(39, "C").Value & " , "
logSTR = logSTR & Cells(40, "C").Value & " , "
logSTR = logSTR & Cells(41, "C").Value & " , "
logSTR = logSTR & Cells(42, "C").Value & " , "
logSTR = logSTR & Cells(46, "C").Value & " , "
logSTR = logSTR & Cells(47, "C").Value & " , "
logSTR = logSTR & Cells(48, "C").Value & " , "
logSTR = logSTR & Cells(49, "C").Value & " , "
logSTR = logSTR & Cells(50, "C").Value & " , "
logSTR = logSTR & Cells(51, "C").Value & " , "
logSTR = logSTR & Cells(52, "C").Value & " , "

Open "Z:\SHARE DRIVE\RequestDirectory\" & ThisWorkbook.Name & ".csv" For Append As #My_filenumber
    Print #My_filenumber, logSTR
Close #My_filenumber

End Sub
```

When I combine the 2 VBA codes together by removing the 'End Sub' at the end of one or the other, I receive an error and must re-add the line to have the code apply successfully; however, in doing such the codes must be applied separately and then the headers are added to the Excel worksheet itself:

```
Sub AddHeaders()
Dim headers() As Variant
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim wb As Workbook

Application.ScreenUpdating = False 'turn this off for the macro to run a little faster

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook

headers() = Array("Header1", "Header2", "Header3", "Header4", "Header5", "Header6",
    "Header7", "Header8", "Header9", "Header10", "Header11", "Header12")
For Each ws In wb.Sheets
    With ws
    .Rows(1).Value = "" 'This will clear out row 1
    For i = LBound(headers()) To UBound(headers())
        .Cells(1, 1 + i).Value = headers(i)
    Next i
    .Rows(1).Font.Bold = True
    End With
Next ws

Application.ScreenUpdating = True 'turn it back on

MsgBox ("Done!")


End Sub
```

I am wondering if there is a straightforward way of applying the VBA code that handles the adding of the headers along with the data being exported from the Excel worksheet to the CSV file without separating the 2 VBA codes?

Thank you for any information you may provide

Comment: Can you post content of this error?

Comment: The error reads - Compile Error: Expected End Sub

Comment: Have you removed also beginning of new macro, for example `Sub AddHeaders()`?

Comment: I just attempted to do as you suggested - the 2 combined VBA codes were able to execute successfully but the headers were still applied to the Excel worksheet and not the exported CSV document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AddHeaders is designed to add a row of headings to the worksheet.  You won't change what it does simply by making it part of the other subroutine.  WriteCSVFile writes a series of values to the text file, to create the CSV.  You can't readily combine the two, but you can add some of the code from the former to the latter, like this.

```
logSTR = logSTR & "header1" & " , "
logSTR = logSTR & "header2" & " , "
logSTR = logSTR & "header3" & " , "
logSTR = logSTR & "header4" & " , "
'continue for each header

logSTR = logSTR & Chr(13)
```

etc.

Add this code IN FRONT of the line that says

```
logSTR = logSTR & Cells(18, "C").Value & " , "
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I just had to add a comma at the end of the Header name to get them to be input into different cells: "logSTR = logSTR & "Header1,". Is there a way to specify that the headers only occupy Row 1 while the remaining cell data being pulled from the Excel spreadsheet populate Row 2?

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I fixed that.  Add the Chr(13) after the last header, and it will do what you want.

Comment: All good - I really appreciate the help with this. I have been able to apply the above solution and achieved the desired results. I am encountering another issue that I am not sure if I should open a new question to address or if this is a quick fix - is there a way to add to the VBA code to have the CSV export 'ignore' blank data cells? For example: if the data from logSTR = logSTR & Cells(36, "C").Value & " , " is blank, proceed with inputting the data from logSTR = logSTR & Cells(37, "C").Value & " , " into that cell rather than leaving it blank and skipping to the next cell?

Comment: So, you don't care if the cells line up with the headings?  What I mean is, if C36 is blank, and you skip it, then C37 won't be in the same column any more, and will be under the wrong heading.  is that OK?

Comment: Yeah I think so - I would end up putting null cells in to adjust the data to be under the applicable column. I ended up posting a more detailed explanation of the circumstance as well as what I am aiming for and a few people put some suggestions out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40593460/ignoring-blank-cells-in-csv-export-of-excel-worksheet-data

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to put `Close` on teh end of the second macro?

```
Sub WriteCSVFile()

Dim My_filenumber As Integer
Dim logSTR As String

My_filenumber = FreeFile

logSTR = logSTR & Cells(18, "C").Value & " , "
logSTR = logSTR & Cells(19, "C").Value & " , "
logSTR = logSTR & Cells(20, "C").Value & " , "
logSTR = logSTR & Cells(21, "C").Value & " , "
logSTR = logSTR & Cells(22, "C").Value & " , "
logSTR = logSTR & Cells(26, "C").Value & " , "
logSTR = logSTR & Cells(27, "C").Value & " , "
logSTR = logSTR & Cells(28, "C").Value & " , "
logSTR = logSTR & Cells(29, "C").Value & " , "
logSTR = logSTR & Cells(30, "C").Value & " , "
logSTR = logSTR & Cells(31, "C").Value & " , "
logSTR = logSTR & Cells(32, "C").Value & " , "
logSTR = logSTR & Cells(36, "C").Value & " , "
logSTR = logSTR & Cells(37, "C").Value & " , "
logSTR = logSTR & Cells(38, "C").Value & " , "
logSTR = logSTR & Cells(39, "C").Value & " , "
logSTR = logSTR & Cells(40, "C").Value & " , "
logSTR = logSTR & Cells(41, "C").Value & " , "
logSTR = logSTR & Cells(42, "C").Value & " , "
logSTR = logSTR & Cells(46, "C").Value & " , "
logSTR = logSTR & Cells(47, "C").Value & " , "
logSTR = logSTR & Cells(48, "C").Value & " , "
logSTR = logSTR & Cells(49, "C").Value & " , "
logSTR = logSTR & Cells(50, "C").Value & " , "
logSTR = logSTR & Cells(51, "C").Value & " , "
logSTR = logSTR & Cells(52, "C").Value & " , "

Open "Z:\SHARE DRIVE\RequestDirectory\" & ThisWorkbook.Name & ".csv" For Append As #My_filenumber
    Print #My_filenumber, logSTR

Dim headers() As Variant
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim wb As Workbook

Application.ScreenUpdating = False 'turn this off for the macro to run a little faster

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook

headers() = Array("Header1", "Header2", "Header3", "Header4", "Header5", "Header6",
    "Header7", "Header8", "Header9", "Header10", "Header11", "Header12")
For Each ws In wb.Sheets
    With ws
    .Rows(1).Value = "" 'This will clear out row 1
    For i = LBound(headers()) To UBound(headers())
        .Cells(1, 1 + i).Value = headers(i)
    Next i
    .Rows(1).Font.Bold = True
    End With
Next ws

Application.ScreenUpdating = True 'turn it back on
Close #My_filenumber

End Sub
```